# Direct Product of a Graded Ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, graded-rings

Let $R$ be a graded ring, for example with nonnegative grading such that

$$R=R_0 \oplus R_1 \oplus \dots$$

Is then  $R^n= R \times \cdots \times R$ a graded ring (not with a trivial grading) ? If so, with what grading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. If $G$ is a monoid (in your case the natural numbers) and $R,S$ are $G$-graded rings, then $R \times S$ has the canonical $G$-grading $(R \times S)_g = \bigoplus_{a+b=g} R_a \times S_b$.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. You seem to be concluding from the abelian group decompositions $R = \bigoplus_{a \in G} R_a$ and $S = \bigoplus_{b \in G} S_b$ that $R \times S \cong \bigoplus_{a, b \in G} (R_a \times S_b) \cong \bigoplus_{g \in G} \bigoplus_{a, b \in G : a+b=g} (R_a \times S_b)$, but the isomorphism $(\bigoplus_x A_x) \times (\bigoplus_y B_y) \cong \bigoplus_x \bigoplus_y (A_x \times B_y)$ is almost never true for abelian groups (one says that "the category of abelian groups is not distributive").